# Have to_json return a mongoid as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In my Rails API, I'd like a Mongo object to return as a JSON string with the Mongo UID as an "id" property rather than as an "_id" object.

I want my API to return the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": "536268a06d2d7019ba000000",
    "created_at": null,
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "536268a06d2d7019ba000000"
    },
    "created_at": null,
}
```

My model code is:

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  def to_json(options={})
    #what to do here?
    # options[:except] ||= :_id  #%w(_id)
    super(options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can monkey patch `Moped::BSON::ObjectId`:

```
module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId   
      def to_json(*)
        to_s.to_json
      end
      def as_json(*)
        to_s.as_json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to take care of the `$oid` stuff and then `Mongoid::Document` to convert `_id` to `id`:

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def serializable_hash(options = nil)
      h = super(options)
      h['id'] = h.delete('_id') if(h.has_key?('_id'))
      h
    end
  end
end
```

That will make all of your Mongoid objects behave sensibly.

Comment: I assume that the first block allow to save returned object correctly, despite of the second.

Comment: @zishe The first one gives you `"536268a06d2d7019ba000000"` instead of `{"$oid":"536268a06d2d7019ba000000"}`, the second one replaces `"_id"` with `"id"` in the JSON.

Comment: I got it:) I just tried to point to the fact, that in case of some api with frontend part, which can modify this object and then send request save it, it won't work. It's mostly relates to @MonkeyBonkey as a warning, not to you solution as en error.

Comment: @zishe It should work fine if you follow the usual pattern: `m = Model.find(id); m.update_attributes(...)`. Or am I missing something? I'm not trying to pick a fight, I am genuinely curious if I've missed something or if something isn't as clear as it could be.

Comment: yes, probably you are right. I made the same thing, so want to be precise.

Comment: I need the exact opposite for mongomapper... it returns string id and I need BSON.

Comment: @dangalg: If you need a `BSON::ObjectId` then you can `BSON::ObjectId.from_string(string_id)`. I've monkey patched a `to_bson_id` method into `String`, `Mongoid::Document`, `BSON::ObjectId`, and `NilClass` to help me deal with this nonsense. Then I can just say `thing.to_bson_id` and not worry about it.

Comment: @muistooshort can you give a code example of how i can monkey patch to_json to make it return bson id and not string?

Comment: @dangalg: But `to_json` is supposed to return JSON (i.e. a string in JSON format). Are you sure that's the right method?

Comment: how to set this?

Answer (score 8):

You can change the data in `as_json` method, while data is a hash:

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

   def as_json(*args)
    res = super
    res["id"] = res.delete("_id").to_s
    res
  end
end

p = Profile.new
p.to_json
```

result:

```
{
    "id": "536268a06d2d7019ba000000",
    ...
}
```

Comment: nice, no need monkey patching and very clearly for specific model.

Answer (score 8):

For guys using Mongoid 4+ use this,

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/354)

Comment: Please no. I just spent 2 hours debugging some extremely weird behaviour, and it turns out this code (copy/pasted into the codebase) was the culprit. `to_s` does not take an optional argument like `as_json` does. @mu is too short's answer accounts for this. Additionally, overriding the method will at least show the monkey patch in the stacktrace. An alias isolated from the original method will be much harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

Use for example:

```
user = collection.find_one(...)
user['_id'] = user['_id'].to_s
user.to_json
```

this return

```
{
    "_id": "54ed1e9896188813b0000001"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  def to_json
    as_json(except: :_id).merge(id: id.to_s).to_json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change default behavior of MongoId, just convert result of as_json.

```rb
profile.map{|k, v| [k, v&.[]('$oid') || v]}.to_h
```

Also, this convert other `BSON::ObjectId` like `user_id`.

EDIT: Also consider recursive structure (e.g. `as_json(root: true)`)

```rb
class Profile
  ...
  def flatten_oid(json)
    if json.is_a?(Hash)
      json.map{|k, v| [k, v&.[]('$oid') || flatten_oid(v)]}.to_h
    else
      json
    end
  end

  def as_json(options={})
   flatten_oid(super)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# config/initializers/mongoid.rb

# convert object key "_id" to "id" and remove "_id" from displayed attributes on mongoid documents when represented as JSON
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def as_json(options={})
      attrs = super(options)
      id = {id: attrs["_id"].to_s}
      attrs.delete("_id")
      id.merge(attrs)
    end
  end
end

# converts object ids from BSON type object id to plain old string
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```