# how to return mongo id as string in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am using Rails 4.1.5 & Mongoid 4.0.
My apis are returning mongo id's as hash

```
{
_id: {
$oid: "541e79bc616b684e75000000"
}
created_at: "2014-09-21T07:09:48.599Z"
}
```

I want something like this

```
{
id: "541e79bc616b684e75000000"
created_at: "2014-09-21T07:09:48.599Z"
}
```

I have checked [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505247/have-to-json-return-a-mongoid-as-a-string) already, but i am not sure in which file i need to put changes mentioned in this answer

Comment: You can just create a file called mongoid.rb, in lib folder.

Comment: i created two files moped.rb & mongoid.rb in libs folder, but issue is not resoved with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505247/have-to-json-return-a-mongoid-as-a-string)

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes, i even tried after droping my development & test mongo DB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a file in config/initializers and put the code there.

UPDATE:

Use the following code:

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    def to_json(*args)
      to_s.to_json
    end

    def as_json(*args)
      to_s.as_json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: issue still exist after moving files to config/initalizers

Comment: I just updated my answer. there is a little change on the patch.

Comment: what will be the name of the file @Zakwan and how to use it? thanks

Comment: I named it mongoid.rb. If that helps.